# SVM+HOG object detector

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm

I ran into a problem when training an SVM+HOG object detector, and this is what I did.
I put all the features in a list called `features` and used

```
X_scaler = StandardScaler().fit(features)
scaled_X = X_scaler.transform(features)
rand_state = np.random.randint(0, 100)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(np.array(features), labels, test_size=0.3, random_state=rand_state)
```

According to `sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler`, this transformation in `StandardScaler()` is based on the mean and standard deviation of all the training samples. So here comes the question, if I want to test my trained SVM on only 1 newly seen sample, how can I apply the `StandardScaler()`? as I cannot calculate the mean and standard deviation from just 1 sample.

From my understanding, if I want to test the SVM on new data (not `x_test`), I need to follow the same procedure from training. Therefore, I tried to extract HOG features from multiple newly seen samples and append to another list called `test_feature`, then

```
X_scaler = StandardScaler().fit(test_feature)
scaled_X = X_scaler.transform(test_feature_feature)
```

seems to be working properly and the SVM produces correct output, but when `len(test_feature) == 1`, no matter I use `StandardScaler()` to transform `test_feature` or directly use `y_pred = clf.predict(np.array(test_feature))`, the output are all garbages.

Any comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fit your `StandardScaler()` on the training data only otherwise your means and variances are going to be bias as they are computed using test data. Once this transformer is fitted, you can perform a `transform()` on your test data and new samples which will scale them according to the calculated mean and variances.

You should:

1. `train_test_split()`
2. `fit()` your `StandardScaler()` using train data
3. `fit()` your model using the transformed train set
4. `transform()` your test data
5. `predict()` transformed test data

As follows:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(np.array(features), labels, test_size=0.3, random_state=rand_state)

scaler = StandardScaler()
    
X_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)

clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)

clf.predict(X_train)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just simply call on **transform**. As you said, the standard scaler uses the training set's mean and standard deviation in transforming the data. The same mean and standard deviation that was already computed using the training set will be applied to the new data. There is no need to recalculate these parameters.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
data = [[0, 0], [0, 0], [1, 1], [1, 1]]
scaler = StandardScaler()
# calling fit will calculate the mean and std
print(scaler.fit(data))
# print out the calcualted mean for example
print(scaler.mean_)
# transform a new data point
print(scaler.transform([[2, 2]]))
```